# Are private members visible across a partial class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code construct, each namespace part being in a separate file in the same project (and the same project folder):

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public partial class Worker
    {
        private ILog log = /*instantiate a logger*/;
    }
}
```

and in a second file

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public partial class Worker
    {
        private void DoStuff()
        {
            log.Info("a message");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it won't compile, because in the second file the VS2008 compiler complains that "The name 'log' does not exist in the current context"

Log has to be declared as public for this to compile, which is a surprise. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - that code works for me, other than that it's not actually valid code because `DoStuff` doesn't have a return type.

Comment: You have a compiler error (`DoStuff` must return a value) so I suspect your copy and paste has eliminated the problem.  Make sure you have the exact same namespace and class name, and that you don't have _another_ log variable/member somewhere.

Comment: To answer the question, _yes_ private members are visible across parts of a partial class.

Comment: Are you sure the namespaces are exactly the same?

Comment: Turned out to be nothing to do with the object log not existing in the current context (not directly, anyway). I had forgotten to reference a method on log. The error message led me astray. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @NeilHaughton: you should delete this question, since it's never going to be reworded into a useful question. Also, this highlights the importance of providing accurate code reproduction: the code in your question clearly didn't match the code you had in your IDE.

Comment: code in your question clearly didn't match the code you had in your IDE. –  Dan Puzey.  It did in the important points. The error that was causing the problem is exactly the same in both my code and the example. I cut it down and anonymised it, that's all. An exact copy and paste would have been full of extraneous detail. But I've apologised for being foolish, and that's as far as I am going to go.

Comment: "Are private members visible across a partial class" is a very good question, and the answers are helpful, so I don't see how it could be off-topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A partial class is just a normal class distributed across various files. The compiler takes all the code, combines it into one and then compiles it. There's no difference in scoping rules for partial classes. The same rules as for any other class apply (yes, private members are accessible throughout all the members of a class, be it partial or not).

Imagine the class was in the same .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
namespace Whatever
{
    partial class Partial
    {
        private int a = 1;
    }

    partial class Partial
    {
        public int A
        {
            get
            {
                return this.a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, private variables are visible across different files in a partial class. The compiler treats all parts of a partial class as if they were in the same file.

To solve your particular problem, have you verified that both partial classes are not only in the same folder, but also both included in the Visual Studio project you're trying to compile? They should both be listed under the project in the Solution Explorer in VS. Also, they should both have their 'Action' property set to 'Compile.'